# Crtl+Shift+Space shortcut in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I started use Visual Studio 2015. In prev version I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut to display Parameter Info, but in current version it not working.

How can I restore it, what is name for this shortcut in keyboardconfiguration?

Comment: If you mean Intellisense it is and was Ctl-Space.

Comment: I always replace the opening brace of my function with a new opening brace to get the parameter info.

Comment: ctrl shift space works fine here

Comment: VS2017: same problem here, although Edit.ParameterInfo is mapped to the correct key sequence. Only way to get parameter info is to retype the open parenthesis or a parameter separator (comma).

Comment: Parameter info is also checked in the text editor settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called **Parameter Info**, or as it appears in the list: `Edit.ParameterInfo`

The default shortcut is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>

So give that a try. It also binds to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in VS 2012/13 as you have mentioned.

It is supposedly supported in VS 2015 too so not sure why it isn't working for you - I seem to recall reading something on SO the other day that was causing shortcut problems, I think it was something to do with keyboard language settings, but I can't seem to find a reference at the moment so don't quote me on that!

---

For a full list of shortcut keys, see these references: [VS 2013](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/), [VS 2015](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/)

You can search for example "Space" and it's not hard to find the one you wanted.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, got it working by doing this:

Go to *Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > General*, *Statement Completion* check *Parameter Information* (like most of the options in the *General* dialog, it was a full black box by default).

Ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ecfczya1(v=vs.100).aspx

[image: My options]

Comment: This should be the answer. Thank you.